# Фотогалерея в Android, как в iOS

Tags: android, iphone

Есть задача: сделать фотогалерею, которая копирует интерфейс и функционал (насколько это возможно). 
Собственное возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Есть ли уже готовые наработки (как SourceForge, только под андроид)?
2. Если писать с нуля, то в какую сторону копать, и сколько времени это может занять (в среднем, я знаю, что точные сроки зависят от разрабов)?

Comment: Копать в сторону Java)

Comment: (в среднем, я знаю, что точные сроки зависят от разрабов), порадовала личная оценка )))

Comment: в среднем зависит от разрабов, а в общем от кого? О_о

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то частями отдаленно похожее есть здесь: [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid).